# Unity assetbundle parsing from a console application (C#)

Tags: unity-game-engine, assetbundle, unity3d-editor

Is it possible to load/parse unity assetbundle from non-unity project (e.g. Console application) using **UnityEngine.dll**?

I want to be able to read the Prefabs from the assetbundle and get the game objects from there...

I tried to reference the **UnityEngine.dll** and to work with the AssetBundle helper from the UnitEngine.dll, like described over here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LoadingAssetBundles.html

But it doesn't run on my console application, probably this code cannot be run outside of unity. When I run the following code

```
WWW www = WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload(@"file://d://Dev/Tests/Unity/AssetBundle/AssetBundles", 1);
```

Or

```
AssetBundle assetBundle = AssetBundle.LoadFromFile(@"file://d://Dev/Tests/Unity/AssetBundle/AssetBundles");
```

I'm getting the next exception:

```
System.Security.SecurityException: 'ECall methods must be packaged into a system module.'
```

Can I use the UnityEngine dll for this purpose? or should I write my own parser?

Comment: Well Asset bundles are entirely different Api. You do not have asset bundle classes in UnityEngine.dll.